# APP Chrome Android - Keyboard Mobile - Type Tel

Tags: android, google-chrome, responsive

I am using on my responsive site, an input tel type. It work properly on the desktop, but on the phone it can enter other keys as (,) , pointer and coma. I tested in Firefox app and works, the problem only occurs in Chrome Mobile.

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function validateNumber(evt) {
                var e = evt || window.event;
                var key = e.keyCode || e.which;

                if (
                key >= 48 && key <= 57 ) {
                    // input is VALID
                }
                else {
                    // input is INVALID
                    e.returnValue = false;
                    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        </script>
        <input onkeypress="validateNumber(event)" type="tel" />
```